# PHP HTML email class selector not working GMAIL

Tags: php

I have code to send HTML email via PHP. It has a table. I want to bold the rounded  in the screenshot. But the arrived email to Gmail is not showing bold and other changes that should be applied to the class selector of "about".

[received email screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbntA.jpg)

Can I use class or ID selector in my style sheet in PHP HTML emails? I do not like to use inline CSS because it is inefficient. I have used them between body.
Here is the code;

```
$to = "xxxx@gmail.com, xxxx@gmail.com"; //multiple recipients with comma separated
$subject = "Here is the subject"; //cannot contain newline characters

$message = "<h1>This is Heading H1</h1>";
$message .= "This is my <b>first</b> line of text.<br>This is my <b>second</b> line of text<br><br>"; //each line should be separated with (\n).  
$message .= "<html>
                <head>
                    <style>
                        body{
                            color:#000000;
                            background-color:#FFFFFF;
                            font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif;
                        }
                        h1{
                            font-size:18px;
                        }
                        p{
                            font-size:12px;
                        }
                        table{
                            background-color:#efefef;
                            border-style:solid;
                            border-width:1px;
                            border-color:#999999;
                        }
                        th{
                            background-color:#cccccc;
                            font-weight:bold;
                            padding:5px;
                        }
                        td{
                            padding:5px;
                        }
                        td.about{
                            font-family:courier, courier-new, serif;
                            font-weight:bold;
                        }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th> About </th>
                            <th> Description </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class=\"about\"> Name </td>
                            <td> Andreas </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class=\"about\"> Address </td>
                            <td> Germany </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class=\"about\"> Message </td>
                            <td> I like your 8 day tour package. What are the rates? </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </body>
            </html>
            "; 

//headers like From, Cc, Bcc, Reply-to, Date ???????????
//$header = "From:raveen1231@gmail.com \r\n"; 
$header = "From: RXXXXX CXXXXX <rxxxx1111@gmail.com> \r\n"; //additional headers should be separated with (\r\n)
//$header .= "Cc: rxxxxx111@gmail.com \r\n";
//$header .= "Bcc: rxxxxx222@gmail.com \r\n";

//always specify MIME version, content type, and character set when sending HTML email
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8 \r\n";
//$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; //////////////////////////////Pls Delete later

$retval = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $header );

if( $retval == true ){
    echo "Message sent successfully";
}
else{
    echo "Message could not be sent!";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried only `.about{...`on your css ?

Comment: @PedroLobito sir, I checked all these variations: .ab{...    ,     td.ab{...      . But gmail do not identify class name. But the Yahoo shows correctly

Comment: The short answer is that, for HTML emails, you will _need_ to inline your CSS to get some semblance of consistency amongst different email clients. HTML email is notoriously tricky because each email client will render CSS and formatting in a different manner.

Comment: Inlining CSS manually is indeed inefficient. You'll want a premailer (there are a bunch, http://premailer.dialect.ca/ is an example) to do that for you.

Comment: @ceejayoz very useful information. thanks

Comment: @ChrisForrence, sir is there any online services that make easy organizing HTML message to be used in PHP mail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML emails are notoriously tricky to get correct; each email client will handle styling in a different manner. Quoting from Lee Munroe's [Things I've Learned About Building & Coding HTML Email Templates](http://www.leemunroe.com/building-html-email/) (emphasis is the author's):

> Email clients use different rendering engines to render HTML emails:
>
> - Apple Mail, Outlook for Mac, Android Mail and iOS Mail use WebKit
> - Outlook 2000/02/03 use Internet Explorer
> - Outlook 2007/10/13 use Microsoft Word (yes, Word!)
> - Web clients use their browser's respective engine e.g. Safari uses WebKit, Chrome uses Blink
>
> Gmail **strips out `<link>` tags and any CSS in the `<style>`** tags, and any other CSS that isn't inlined. Not just Gmail web but also the native Gmail mobile apps.

To directly answer your question, Gmail strips out any `<style>` tags, so you will need to inline your CSS into your HTML elements.

There are a few web services that can inline CSS for you, such as

- [MailChimp](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)
- [ZURB Foundation for Emails](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html)

Furthermore, you can inline it using a library such as [CssToInlineStyles](https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles) so as to handle it purely within your code.